# What should i do with the upgrade?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04

I have dual booted Ubuntu 12.10 and windows 8. Recently, i have upgraded to 13.04 beta but i found there were some problems so i upgraded to beta 2. i lost all the programs i had. I tryed to install google chrome but failed so now i am stuck with chromiun instead. there are many irratating bugs that really get on my nerves and some of the features have been gotten a rid of.

What sould i do wait till ubuntu 13.04 official release comes out or just downgrade back into ubuntu 12.10. I have already made a bootable usb to prepare myself to go back into ubuntu 12.10 but should i do it. is it really worth the time and patience.

Comment: Don't expect any big changes between the actual beta and the final release. If it's working for you downgrade and try again in some months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The next Ubuntu release will be on the 25th, so you will have to wait a couple days. It sounds like your installation is broken anyway, so consider installing 12.10 again and the upgrading to 13.04 once it is out. If you can live without Ubuntu for a couple days, then just wait.

I would not fix the Beta install.

Comment: Thank you for answerring. I thought you might have said that but i would like to see what other people think before doing anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is what i would do loosing all your apps etc suck lol. there is a nifty little test drive ubuntu iso. if you are like me you want to see results for yourself or stay current test it there first, still learning that myself. i can change the OS everyday just to see what is new. P.S Ubuntu one is my best friend format delete whatever your data is safe.  Btw i believe WIN7/Win8 are like rivals to ubuntu. best results are dependent on What OS was installed first and Second